# JQuery Filtering - Buttons and Search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filtering

I am looking to filter this table with **BOTH** clickable buttons "and" input search. I have a button group where each button has an onclick event to filter the rows and the search filter the rows with the keyup function. Each one works separately but I would like them to work together.

1.Click a button ( rows filtered )

2.Add text search ( visible rows filtered again )

or visa versa or just step 1 or step 2

FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/rbla/Lh3kpxg2/29/

```js
var $rowsss = $('#table tr:visible');

$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rowsss.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});


$("#all").click(function() {
  var rows = $("#table").find("tr").show();
});

$("#green").click(function() {
  var rows = $("#table").find("tr").hide();
  rows.filter(":contains('Green')").show();
});

$("#orange").click(function() {
  var rows = $("#table").find("tr").hide();
  rows.filter(":contains('Orange')").show();
});

$("#lemon").click(function() {
  var rows = $("#table").find("tr").hide();
  rows.filter(":contains('Lemon')").show();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  width: 209px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  width: 100px;
}

.buttons-wrapper {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

.my-radio-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999em;
  top: -9999em;
}

.my-radio-button+label {
  float: left;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #28608f;
  margin-right: -1px;
  color: #fff;
  /* background-color: #428bca; */
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
}

.my-radio-button+label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: .7em 0 0 .7em;
}

.my-radio-button+label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 .7em .7em 0;
}

.my-radio-button:checked+label {
  /* background-color: #3277b3; */
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons-wrapper">

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="1" id="all" checked />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="2" id="green" />
  <label for="green">Green</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="3" id="orange" />
  <label for="orange">Orange</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="4" id="lemon" />
  <label for="lemon">Lemon</label>

</div><br clear="all">

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">

<table id="table">

  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code now

1. handles backspace/empty field
2. handles clicking a button while search field is filled
3. will clear the search if you click all
4. is pretty DRY

You can get rid of the titleCase function if you change the IDs of the buttons to be the same as the second column OR if you change the second column to have the lowercase ID as an attribute

```js
const count = () => {
  $("#count").text($("#table tbody tr:visible").length);
};
const titleCase = val => val.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
$(function() {
  $('#search').on("input", function() {
    const val = $(this).val().replace(/ +/g, ' ').trim().toLowerCase();
    const but = titleCase($(".my-radio-button:checked").attr("id"));
    if (val === "" && but === "all") {
      $('#table tr').show();
      count();
      return;
    }
    $('#table tr').each(function() {
      const found = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1;
      let show = (but === "All" && found) || ($(this).filter(":contains(" + but + ")").length > 0 && found)
      $(this).toggle(show);
    })
    count()
  });

  $(".my-radio-button").on("click", function() {
    if (this.id === "all") {
      $("#table tr").show();
      $('#search').val(""); // Clear input on click of ALL
    } else {
      const rows = $("#table").find("tr").hide();
      const val = titleCase(this.id);
      rows.filter(":contains(" + val + ")").show();
      $('#search').trigger("input");
    }
    count();
  });
  count();
  $("#total").text($("#table tbody tr").length);
}); // end of $(function() {
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  width: 209px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  width: 100px;
}

.buttons-wrapper {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

.my-radio-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999em;
  top: -9999em;
}

.my-radio-button+label {
  float: left;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #28608f;
  margin-right: -1px;
  color: #fff;
  /* background-color: #428bca; */
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
}

.my-radio-button+label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: .7em 0 0 .7em;
}

.my-radio-button+label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 .7em .7em 0;
}

.my-radio-button:checked+label {
  /* background-color: #3277b3; */
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons-wrapper">

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="1" id="all" checked />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="2" id="green" />
  <label for="green">Green</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="3" id="orange" />
  <label for="orange">Orange</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="4" id="lemon" />
  <label for="lemon">Lemon</label>

</div><br clear="all">

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search" autocomplete="off"> <span id="count"></span>/<span id="total"></span>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lemon</td>
      <td>Black</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lemon</td>
      <td>Black</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lemon</td>
      <td>Black</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tfoot>
      </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: click green and then click all - all rows are hidden

Comment: type something in search and then back it out - wont return all rows

Comment: Ok, this now handles backspace and click on buttons while searching and clicking all

Comment: I am now clicking on the buttons and nothing is happening - here is your code - jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rbla/4wo3z7ur/7/

Comment: I would like to account for all scenarios and combos - click or search maybe 1 maybe both.. thx

Comment: Yeah - I missed `&& but==="all"` in the search resetting when val === "" - try again

Comment: I am testing it out now - https://codepen.io/rblanc/pen/gOrmXgr - looks good so far - I will test more later today - great job and thanks - I will mark this as answer...

Comment: Im also wanting to count visible rows ( and display ) at any point ( if you are up for another challenge )

Comment: 1. type in "app" 2. back it out 3. click lemon 4. click all. - counter not working - thx

Comment: also - I think you need to lose the last " }) "

Comment: Of course not. If it was wrong, the code would not work at all

Comment: Added two more count()

Answer (score 0):

Only edited JavaScript:

```js
var $rowsss = $('#table tr:visible');
const $search = $('#search');
let groupFilter = 'all';

const searchAll = () => {
  var val = $.trim($search.val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rowsss.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    const hasGroup = groupFilter == 'all' || text.indexOf(groupFilter) >= 0;
    const notHasSearch = !~text.indexOf(val);
    return !hasGroup || notHasSearch;
  }).hide();

  return true;
}

$search.keyup(() => searchAll());

$(".my-radio-button").click(function() {
  groupFilter = this.id;
  searchAll()
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  width: 209px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  width: 100px;
}

.buttons-wrapper {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

.my-radio-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999em;
  top: -9999em;
}

.my-radio-button+label {
  float: left;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #28608f;
  margin-right: -1px;
  color: #fff;
  /* background-color: #428bca; */
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
}

.my-radio-button+label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: .7em 0 0 .7em;
}

.my-radio-button+label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 .7em .7em 0;
}

.my-radio-button:checked+label {
  /* background-color: #3277b3; */
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons-wrapper">

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="1" id="all" checked />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="2" id="green" />
  <label for="green">Green</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="3" id="orange" />
  <label for="orange">Orange</label>

  <input type="radio" class="my-radio-button" name="radioButtonTest" value="4" id="lemon" />
  <label for="lemon">Lemon</label>

</div><br clear="all">

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">

<table id="table">

  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code I found on other forums:

```
<form class="filter-form" action="">
          <div class="input-field">
          <div class="accessories-display-subtitle"><h2>BRANDS</h2><div class="divider"></div></div>
          <div class="input-field-content">
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="raleigh" id="raleigh"><label for="raleigh">Raleigh</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="focus" id="focus"><label for="focus">Focus</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="felt" id="felt"><label for="felt">Felt</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="specialized" id="specialized"><label for="specialized">Specialized</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="trek" id="trek"><label for="trek">Trek</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="pinarello" id="pinarello"><label for="pinarello">Pinarello</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="bmc" id="bmc"><label for="bmc">BMC</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="giant" id="giant"><label for="giant">Giant</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="salsa" id="salsa"><label for="salsa">Salsa</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="cannondale" id="cannondale"><label for="cannondale">Cannondale</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="cervelo" id="cervelo"><label for="cervelo">Cervelo</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="bianchi" id="bianchi"><label for="bianchi">Bianchi</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="trinx" id="trinx"><label for="trinx">Trinx</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="spanker" id="spanker"><label for="spanker">Spanker</label></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
          <div class="accessories-display-subtitle"><h2>PRICE RANGE</h2><div class="divider"></div></div>
          <div class="input-field-content">
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="6-7k" id="6-7k"><label for="6-7k">₱6000 - ₱7000</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="8-9k" id="8-9k"><label for="8-9k">₱8000 - ₱9000</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="10-20k" id="10-20k"><label for="10-20k">₱10000 - ₱95000</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="20-40k" id="20-40k"><label for="20-40k">₱95000 - ₱40000</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="40-60k" id="40-60k"><label for="40-60k">₱40000 - ₱60000</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="60-80k" id="60-80k"><label for="60-80k">₱60000 - ₱80000</label></div>
            <div class="checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="80upk" id="80upk"><label for="80upk">₱80000 and higher</label></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-buttons">
              <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="filter">
              <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
            </div>
          </form>

<div class="flowers">
  <div class="flower" data-id="aloe" data-category="giant trinx">Aloe</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="lavendar" data-category="purple green medium africa europe">Lavender</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="stinging-nettle" data-category="green large africa europe asia">Stinging Nettle</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="gorse" data-category="green yellow large europe">Gorse</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="hemp" data-category="green large asia">Hemp</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="titan-arum" data-category="purple other giant asia">Titan Arum</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="golden-wattle" data-category="green yellow large australasia">Golden Wattle</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="purple-prairie-clover" data-category="purple green other medium north-america">Purple Prairie Clover</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="camellia" data-category="pink other large north-america">Camellia</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="scarlet-carnation" data-category="red medium north-america">Scarlet Carnation</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="indian-paintbrush" data-category="red medium north-america">Indian Paintbrush</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="moss-verbena" data-category="purple other small south-america">Moss Verbena</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="climbing-dayflower" data-category="blue tiny south-america">Climbing Dayflower</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="antarctic-pearlwort" data-category="green yellow large antarctica">Antarctic Pearlwort</div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {

  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);

  });

 
  var $filteredResults = $('.flower');


  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {


    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {



        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.flower').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();

});
</script>
```